# Why does sparking occur while unplugging a 40V DC, 6A load from a source?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, battery-charging, high-voltage, spark

To start with, the problem was two-fold (sparking at plug-in as well as at unplug).

[image]

The plug-in problem was solved by introducing a delay in MOSFET 'turn-on.'

Would there be a way to solve the unplug problem too?

Comment: Exactly what is the load?

Comment: 40 V and 6 A is a pretty substantial DC spark! Can you turn off the load or the supply before unplugging?

Comment: @winny, I have to do it with automatic switch, I can not use any manual switch or anything to turn on or off, I have an option of plug-in and plug-out only.

Answer (score 1):

You have solved 'sparking at plug-in' by delaying mosfet 'turn-on'.

Likewise you could avoid 'sparking at plug-out' by first turning off the mosfet and then plugging out the load.

You would need to wire an additional switch to the controller.

Comment: but how can I identify plug-out activity in advance?

Comment: Then you would need to explain what this plug-in and plug-out is all about!

Comment: I have a dc connector ( Reference: -  https://bm-es.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/XT60.jpg ), one of them is connected with SMPS and another one is mentioned above DC Connector. Plug-in means when the user connect this pair and plug-out means user disconnect this pair.

Comment: Would not a switch, wired to the microcontroller to turn off the mosfet before plugging off, be feasible?

Comment: so, I can turn off the gate in case of when the connector is not connected. so, when the user connects the connector the gate is already switched off. but how can I get the idea about that the plug-out activity in advance?

Comment: Could you use a microswitch, actuated by the plug, to turn on the mosfet?

Comment: I can't use that type of configuration, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Design a plug with one short pin carrying low power. When this pin disconnects you have very little time to disconnect power via the MOSFET before the power pins disconnect.